# apply a function to pandas dataframe, choosing variable name and value in parameters

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to use a function that allows me to call both variable name (in this case v1) and variable value ("A"), but here I cannot use v1 as a parameter of the function

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'v1': pd.Categorical(["A","A","B","C"]),'v2': pd.Categorical(["N","S","W","E"])})

def select (token,x):

    comp=df[df.x==token]
    print (comp)
select("A",v1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need only change selecting by attribute `.x` to more general `[x]`:

```
comp=df[df.x==token]
```

to:

```
comp=df[df[x]==token]
```

All together:

```
def select (token,x):
    comp=df[df[x]==token]
    print (comp)
    return comp

print (select("A",'v1'))
  v1 v2
0  A  N
1  A  S
```